# Style the 'Update' or 'Publish' WP button from functions.php or style.css

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

Due to current permission issues to core files and respective stylesheets -- I am wondering how I could customize the LOCATION and APPEARANCE of the Wordpress CMS post / page 'Update / Publish' button?

I have tried pulling the selector from developer tools and declaring `!important` with the new styles within `header.php` and `styles.css` with no such luck -- any suggestions on stylizing the publish / update button -- maybe from within '`functions.php`'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New Admin Stylesheet

You'll need to enqueue a custom stylesheet for the admin like this:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style-admin.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Then create a css file called `style-admin.css`, place it in a directory in your theme folder called css and put something like this in it:

```
.wp-core-ui #publishing-action .button.button-large {
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

### Insert Style into Admin

If you can't create a new stylesheet like that, you can use the `admin_head` hook to insert in into the admin header like so:

```
function my_custom_admin_head() {
    echo '<style>.wp-core-ui #publishing-action .button.button-large {font-size: 28px; height: 50px;}</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_head' );
```